# Meaning of "何か来るんやろなとは思ったけどな"

Tags: translation, slang

I saw [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cw1b.jpg) pic on 9gag.com! I was able to read the following line perfectly (or maybe not): 何か来るんやろなとは思ったけどな. I'm not sure what it exactly means, but I have a feeling that this is slang.

1. 来る means to come, but what does 来るんやろな mean?
2. 思った means "thought" and けど means something like "but". However, I do not know how the addition of な changes the meaning of the phrase.

Here's the page from 9gag in which the image was posted:
http://9gag.com/gag/6856310

Comment: やろな would be だろな (i think/wonder..) in Kansai-dialect...
so translated, "I thought something is coming, but..."

Comment: For the record, this looks like the new year's eve special ガキの使い、笑ってはいけない. 楳図 (Umezu) かずお is a famous horror manga artist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usage of な simply emphasizes the sentence.

> 何か来るんやろなとは思ったけどな
>   ＝［［何かが来る］のだろうな］と思ったけどな
>   = [[something-GA come-NONPAST]-NOMINALIZER right-NA]-QUOTE thought but-NA

Literally, "I thought something must come, but..."

However, usage of けど at the end of the sentence like that generally means something inferable, and in this case it's something like "but I wasn't expecting this". (Just guessing from the screenshot.)

A more liberal translation is "I knew something was going to show up, but not this!"

(P.S., the nominalizer ん／の is there because だろう is a form of the copula だ, which takes a nominal (noun-like) object. There is another form of だろう which modifies verbs, but this is not it, though they are tightly related semantically.)